# HTML5 input pattern for French licence plate number

Tags: html, design-patterns

I'm searching for a html pattern to check an input field containing a licence plate number.

Problem is we have many possible patterns :

- AA-123-ZZ
- 1234-AZ-09
- 123-ABC-90

Can you help me write such a pattern ?
Cherry on the cake would be if the user can write the - or not.

Thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should cover the three input options as specified:

```
<form action="carCheck.asp" method="post">
  Number Plate: <input type="text" name="number plate" pattern="^([A-Za-z]{2}-?[0-9]{3}-?[A-Za-z]{2})?([0-9]{4}-?[A-Za-z]{2}-?[0-9]{2})?([0-9]{3}-?[A-Za-z]{3}-?[0-9]{2})?$" title="French Number Plate">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Edit: also worth considering is restricted/unused characters in French Number plates (I,O,U)...

```
pattern="^((?![IOUiou])[A-Za-z]{2}-?[0-9]{3}-?(?![IOUiou])[A-Za-z]{2})?([0-9]{4}-?(?![IOUiou])[A-Za-z]{2}-?[0-9]{2})?([0-9]{3}-?(?![IOUiou])[A-Za-z]{3}-?[0-9]{2})?$"
```

EDIT: 2nd pattern above to allow lowercase alpha as well as uppercase.

This should cover:

Aa-999-Aa and Aa999Aa

9999-Aa-99 and 9999Aa99

999-AaA-99 and 999AaA99

Comment: This pattern solutes everything that I want to achieve, unfortunately, it doesn't work. For each combination, I have the little pop-up telling me I didn't match the pattern.

Comment: I've pasted my second pattern into your codepen and it works.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
pattern="^[A-Z0-9]{1,4}-?[A-Z0-9]{1,4}-?[A-Z0-9]{1,4}$"
```

3 groups of A-Z/0-9 (1 to 4 symbols), separated by (maybe missing) hypens.

Edit: if you want each group to contain only letters or only numbers, pattern will be the following:

```
pattern="^([A-Z]{1,4}|[0-9]{1,4})-?([A-Z]{1,4}|[0-9]{1,4})-?([A-Z]{1,4}|[0-9]{1,4})$"
```

Also, Paul McCombie's answer below contains an amendment on characters unused in license plates, you may want to look at it too.

**Update:**

```
pattern="^([A-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}|[0-9]{3,4})-?([A-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{3})-?([A-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})$"
```

Comment: TIL html input could do regex.

Comment: Thank you. This regex works great but it's still too permissive to me. For instance, the user can input 'AAAA-1111-AAAA'. The goal here is to forbid invalid licence plate.

Comment: @Pauloscorps what are the further limitations? Length of groups? Please elaborate - I'll correct my solution then.

Comment: In the ideal, I would have want exactly what @Paul McCombie has done. Allow 3 patterns : AA-111-AA, 1111-AA-11, 111-AAA-11. He also added the character exclusions : I, O, U.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. I made a pen for you to test. http://codepen.io/Pauloscorps/pen/qNOEpq

Comment: @Pauloscorps can you please post a sample of a valid license number that fails? (or a sample of invalid license number that produces a false positive?) All 3 patterns work ok in the codepen.

Comment: @Pauloscorps also, you've misplaced my pattern for Paul's and vice versa in the Codepen.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solution for your problem That need Regex:

- [HTML5 input pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).
- Using javaScript to validate input with regex.[Test now](https://regex101.com/r/vA9zU6/1)

#### HTML5 input pattern

> The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against.

```
<input type="text" name="licence" pattern="(\w+-\w+-\w+)"title="Your input">
```

---

#### Javascript Regex

```
var re = /(\w+-\w+-\w+)/; 
var str = '123-ABC-90';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```